# Passing arguments to a function which is created using the new function keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am converting a string to function expression using `new Function()`.

It is working fine, but I need to pass arguments to the function. How to do that?

I am reading the string from a JSON file.

```
var act = new Function("Hosting.Click()");
act();
```

Comment: Do you need to pass an argument to `act`, or to `Hosting.Click`?

Comment: a simple example var printNumber = new Function('A', 'console.log("Number is "+A)');
printNumber(10); but creating functions this way is considered bad.

Comment: I want to pass to Hosting.Click function.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming there is really no better way to do this**.

You would need to parse the string which contains the code, and substitute arguments in there.

For example, if the pattern was always a method call, you could split it on the parenthesis, and join arguments inside. However, if it was always a function call, you'd be better off splitting out the parts and calling the function directly (will give you a chance to ensure the string is what you're expecting).

Comment: I have tried like this                                                       var sample = 'test';
        var act = new Function(Hosting.Click+'('+sample+')');
        act();                                                              but it throws test is not defined exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

creating new Function with `arg1` and then calling `Hosting.Click()` by passing this argument

```js
var Hosting={Click:function(){
alert(JSON.stringify(arguments));
}}

var act = new Function("arg1","Hosting.Click(arg1)");
act("Value for argument 1");
```

**Update :-**

For any no of arguments -

```
var act2 = new Function("Hosting.Click.apply(window,arguments)");
act2("any no of arguments",1,2,3,4,5,"Hi");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/pz3s2k79/)